# Android и MySQL через PHP и Json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Посоветуйте, как наиболее свежие источники или литературу, в которой можно узнать про соединение `android` приложения c `MySQL` с помощью `PHP` и `Json` и примеры к ним.

Смотрел различные источники: в некоторых устарели методы, в других используют свои библиотеки, в третьих вообще не на русском или английском.

Литературу или статьи желательно на русском, но если нет, то и на английском пойдет. 
Интересуют основные операции по добавлению, выборке, удалению и обновлению данных на Базе данных.

Comment: На Андроиде вообще то Ява используется. Каким боком тут PHP?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov PHP в смысле серверного языка, прослойки между Android и MySQL

Comment: Будьте конкретнее и пишите точнее, тогда будет более понятно что вам нужно. MySQL, опять же, с Адроида или с PHP будет использоваться?

Comment: Android передает параметры и ожидает ответы от страницы PHP, которая делает запросы к бд

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Android ожидает ответы в формате json

Comment: В таком случае поиск по этим ключевым словам должен выдать вам нужное, например http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql/ . Для вывода данных со страницы можно использовать echo json_encode($data)

Comment: Вы предоставили источник по подключению php к MySQL, а мне нужно источники, где android связывается с php-страницей и получает ответ от нее

Comment: А это уже смотря какую версию Андроидного SDK вы будете использовать. Пример из самой последней - https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос очень обширный, но попробую автору дать хотя бы направление "куда копать".
Как варианты (список не полный):

1. `REST API` + `JSON`, старый проверенный способ со своими плюсами и минусами. Легко гуглится (`Retrofit` + `GSON`) для Android, для PHP уверен что тоже.
2. `GraphQL`, новое перспективное направление, сложнее с технической
   точки зрения, но более элегантное с точки зрения архитектуры и
   гибкости обмена данными.

Так что разбейте свою задачу на две части (клиент и сервер), выберите протокол обмена данными и и решайте независимо.

https://graphql.org/